# Sequence of $r_n:=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ where $x_n$ is a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, fibonacci-numbers

Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a function on some complete metric space $(X,d)$. Let, $x_n$ is a sequence in the metric space defined by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ and starting from $x_0$.

My questions are

(1) What are the conditions on $f$ so that the sequence $r_{n}:=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n},\ n\ge 0$ converges in $X$? (Here division is coordinate wise) In particular what happens when $f$ is a contraction?

(2) What are the conditions on $f$ so that $r_n$ converges in $X$ though $x_n$ does not? An example of such a sequence $x_n$ and its associated $r_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the sequence $x_n$ constructed from the Fibonacci sequence $u_n$ where $$x_n=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{n+1}\\
u_n
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}x$$ with $x_0=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$.

**EDIT:** The definition of $r_n$ that I have given is okay with $\mathbb{R}^n$, but is meaningless for a general metric space. Can it be modified accordingly?

Comment: Even when you're in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you should still be careful not to divide by $0$ in your definition of the $r_n$....

Comment: That is the whole point, if one of the coordinates is $\infty$ then sequence diverges. So whether it will be $0$ or not depends on the mapping $f$ and initial point $x_0$. For example you'll not find a zero in any coordinate of $r_n$ for the Fibonacci derived sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: How do you divide a vector by a vector? What you are perhaps meaning is that you have a continuous scalar function $g:X\to\mathbb R$ and set $r_k=g(x_{k+1})/g(x_k)$, in the Fibonacci example $g$ could be the projection on the first component.

Comment: @LutzL, First of all I'm talking about component wise division, which is closely related to the Hadamard product of two vectors. What you are saying is also a perfectly okay way of construction of a sequence, but then you can, depending upon the properties of the function $g$ easily comment on the convergence of the sequence constructed. But for my case, I do not know if it is that easy to infer.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay, in that case you then have for each component a continuous function, the projection on that component. This is not different from the scalar case, as long as it stays in finite dimensions.

Comment: Okay, so @LutzL, are you saying that if the sequence $x_n$ is convergent, for finite dimensional case, then so will be the sequence $r_n$ as defined by me?

Comment: If you can exclude division by zero, then yes. This would follow from the elementary arithmetic rules of limits. I'd think that if $\lim_k g(x_k)=0$ then anything can happen to the limit of the ratios.

Comment: Yes, I understand and the argument seems plausible but the only thing is that there may be contractions $f$ for which some coordinates of $x_n$ can be $0$ at some $n$ and that would make $r_n$ sequence divergent. That means we still can not say that the sequence $r_n$ is convergent if $x_n$ is. But of course, otherwise it seems to be true.